# The order of images selected by intents is not same

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am selecting multiple images through intent in java. But here problem is that the order in which I am selecting the images in gallery is not same as shown in recyclerview.
Below is the code . Please tell me the solution.

```
 private void pickAns(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT,  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE , true);

        intent.setType("image/*");
        launcherAns.launch(intent);
    }



    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcherAns = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result != null && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                Anslist = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<imageModal> imageList =  new ArrayList<>();
                imageUri = new ArrayList<>();
                images = new ArrayList<>();
                ClipData clips = result.getData().getClipData();

                ansImgRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (clips == null) {

                    Uri imgUri = result.getData().getData();
                    imageUri.add(imgUri);
                    try {

                        // upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(addQuesPage.this.getContentResolver(), imgUri);

                        String str = encodeBitmapImage(bitmap);
                        images.add(str);
                        imageList.add(new imageModal(str));
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes);
                        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(addQuesPage.this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "image", "val");
                        byte[] bytee = bytes.toByteArray();
                        Anslist.add(new productImageModal(bytee));


                        addProductImageAdapter adapter = new addProductImageAdapter(Anslist, addQuesPage.this);
                        ansImgRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                        // GridLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(addQuestion.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                        GridLayoutManager layout = new GridLayoutManager(addQuesPage.this, 1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                        ansImgRecycler.setLayoutManager(layout);

                        //TwoRowGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new TwoRowGridLayoutManager(context, 2);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }else{
                    if (0 < clips.getItemCount()) {
                        if (clips != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < clips.getItemCount(); i++) {

                                Uri imgUri = clips.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                imageUri.add(clips.getItemAt(0).getUri());
                                try {
                                    //  upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(addQuesPage.this.getContentResolver(), imgUri);
                                    String str = encodeBitmapImage(bitmap);

                                    images.add(str);

                                    imageList.add(new imageModal(str));
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes);
                                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(addQuesPage.this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "image", "val");
                                    byte[] bytee = bytes.toByteArray();
                                    Anslist.add(new productImageModal(bytee));


                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }

                            }

                            addProductImageAdapter adapter = new addProductImageAdapter(Anslist, addQuesPage.this);
                            ansImgRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                            GridLayoutManager layout = new GridLayoutManager(addQuesPage.this, 1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                            ansImgRecycler.setLayoutManager(layout);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(addQuesPage.this, "No image founddddddddddddddddd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(addQuesPage.this, "Select atleast 1 images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pick();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }


    });
```

I was trying to select multiple images in a certain order but it is not same as shown in recyclerview

Comment: This has nothing to do with a recycle view. You just receive uris in clip data in a different sequence then you expect. You can do nothing to it.

Comment: is there any way to exact sequence in which images were selected ?

Answer (score 0):

> But here problem is that the order in which I am selecting the images in gallery is not same as shown in recyclerview

There is no requirement for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to honor `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. Where it does, there is no requirement for the implementation to track the order in which the user selects images, and there is no requirement for the returned result to reflect that selection order.

> Please tell me the solution.

Allow the user to set the order within your app, such as via drag-and-drop.